# MySQL QUERY TO DROP DATA WHICH ARE COMMON IN TWO DATABASES RDS (MYSQL DB'S)

Tags: mysql, sql

e.g.:

```
         **table 1**

 name     gender  email

 hemanth    m       test@gmail.com 
 rajesh     m       rajesh@gmail.com 
 kumar      m       kumar@gmail.com

      **table 2***

 name     gender    email

 hemanthsai m       testing@gmail.com 
 rajesh     m       rajesh@gmail.com 
 kumaras    f       kumaras@gmail.com

     **expected result in table 1***

 name     gender    email

 hemanthsai m       testing@gmail.com 
 rajesh     m       rajesh@gmail.com 
 kumaras    f       kumaras@gmail.com
```

this is just an example, in reality i have to update all the data with many columns at a time in mysql

What I've tried was

```
     INSERT INTO table1 (NAME,gender, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET *;    ### this didn""t worked ###
```

I need something like:

```
     INSERT INTO table1 * ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET *;
```

If this didn't work then I thought of delete common values on one table using another table and then insert the left values into the deleted table, so I need query to delete common values on one table based on another table..

thanks in advance,

Comment: Caps lock?  No need to scream.

Comment: haha :) little Frustation

Comment: Don't go all PHP CEO on us, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `INSERT INTO SELECT`?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `table1`
(`name`, `gender`, `email`)
SELECT t2.`name`, t2.`gender`, t2.`email`
FROM `table2` AS t2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`name`= t2.`name`,`gender` = t2.`gender`, `email` = t2.`email`
```

You also need to have a unique key which is common between table1 and table2. I assume that is the case.

**EDIT**

Taking your comment into account, what you are looking for might be `REPLACE INTO`.

```
REPLACE INTO `table1` 
SELECT *
FROM `table2`
```

Please note that this operation doesn't update the old values, but actually deletes them. This means that the `PRIMARY_KEY` might be replaced if it has for instance `auto_increment()`.
Also note that this is a heavy operation as the table needs to be reindexed for every delete operation.

You can read more about it here: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice

Personally I would use `INSERT INTO` even if there are many columns

Comment: Yeah understood but It'll have huge data already I'm using a query which deletes the common records between two tables but it is taking so much time to process

Answer (score 0):

Create another table:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  name VARCHAR(50),
  gender VARCHAR(50),
  email VARCHAR(50));
```

Create a unique index on the new table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table3 (name, gender, email);
```

Do `INSERT IGNORE` from both of table1 & table2:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table3 SELECT * FROM table1;

INSERT IGNORE INTO table3 SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Check your `table3`, it should't have any duplicates anymore.

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kwgtt2wgsbSmxEZNVwg3s8/0)

P/S: If you want to only check duplicate email - and allow same user having multiple emails, you can skip creating unique index and make `email` column in `table3` as `PRIMARY KEY` instead.

Comment: It is giving kind of UNION operation but i want to do UPSERT Operation on two tables..

Comment: you mean if `table1` don't have the data in `table2` it will insert and if `table1` have the data but some field have different value; e.g. name and gender are same but email is different, then you want to update the email value in `table1` using email value from `table2`?

Comment: actually now we have only two or three columns but in reality i will have more columns like 108 columns so if i want to update all it's a tough so, I need something like UPDATE SET *